# I'm logged in, but trying to vote prompts me to log in

Tags: support, voting, login

I'm registered and logged in, asked several questions so far and accepted several answers, but was never able to vote!  It says "Please login or register to vote for this post."

What can I do?

Comment: just to mention: I always login with my facebook account, I'm on ubuntu, and it happens both in chrome and firefox

Comment: somehow it works on mathoverflow but not on math.stachexchange

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for errors, maybe it will give some direction.

Comment: thanks, how can i do it on chrome?

Comment: Click on the three parallel lines icon to the right of the address bar --> Tools --> JavaScript console. (Or press CTRL+SHIFT+J)

Comment: I got into some kind of console (F12->Console), but when I click "vote" i see nothing there

Comment: Well, it means no errors. You also have Network tab in the tools, click that tab reload the page and you'll see bunch of requests.. any of those result in error? (Status different from 200 or 304)

Comment: when i click vote i get some 204 "no content" and one js "pending"

Comment: Weird. When I vote, I see only JSON request and same when undoing the vote: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1akrM.png (first is for upvote, second is for undoing it) can you please post screenshot of what it looks like for you?

Comment: I have the same problem. Console shows:
POST http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login/global 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:141
c.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:141
c.extend.post jquery.min.js:134
messageCallback global-login.js:57

Comment: @BadgerGirl: I've removed your bounty, since it's impossible to answer this question without knowing more about the problem behind it (that said, please refer to the troubleshooting information in my answer). If you're still having this problem, please contact us using the link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check when you encounter a problem like this:

1. Make sure you're really logged in: do you see your username at the top of the screen? Do you see the "StackExchange" link and logo to the left of it? Click the little down-arrow next to the words "StackExchange", and verify that you get a drop-down with an "inbox" link  at the top (among other things). If you don't see your name, or the drop-down doesn't load, then you're not logged in.
2. Make sure JavaScript is loaded. Do you see a big bar across the top of the page that looks like this?

   [image: Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled]

   Also, make sure you're able to load our scripts from our CDN: can you load http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js directly? If not, figure out why; it's not gonna work until you do.
3. Some versions of Firefox have, in circumstances I've never been able to reproduce, a nasty tendency to cache pages that they really shouldn't. Try clearing your cache *and history.* Yes, really. Don't know why, but that works for some people.
4. Make sure you're not behind a dodgy proxy or web filter. If you are, all bets are off.
5. Make sure you're not trying to *force* a HTTPS connection to the site (with a tool like HTTPS Everywhere) - until SE *supports* HTTPS, this is going to have bad results.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of things that can go wrong, so it's impossible to know for sure what's causing your problem without more detail.